# Run R script in java code and output r result into text file

Tags: java, r

I am trying to run R script in java program and output the result into text file.

Here is my java code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class rclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String line;

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RScript /Users/test.R iphone5 2012-12-16 2013-01-03");
            p.waitFor();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);

            }

            input.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I output r result into text file:

```
out<-capture.output(scores)
cat(out, file="/Users/mmmmmm/Desktop/result.txt", sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

When I run the java code, there's no output from my r script into text file. But when I run the command from terminal, it works well. I cannot to find the problem. Could anyone please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution because I can't reproduce the problem. But why not to output the result using `Rscript` in a file?

For example , You can do somthing like this to put the output and error in the same file

```
 RScript /Users/test.R iphone5 2012-12-16 2013-01-03 > result.txt 2>&1
```